# Is there a way to enforce branch merging restrictions in GitHub?

Tags: github, branching-and-merging

I want to enforce some restrictions on the master branch in GitHub.
 - The master branch should be merged only from *release* branch. How do I enforce this rule?

Answer (score 0):

You could at least start with [protecting the `master` branch](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-protected-branches), enforcing a rule like requiring a [review change](https://help.github.com/en/articles/approving-a-pull-request-with-required-reviews)

That would give you the opportunity to review and merge request, and accepting only the ones coming from the release branch.